# Want to create a chronological row # then reset based on font color

Tags: excel, vba, colors, fonts, chronological

I want to create a column that numbers itself chronologically based on the column to its left based on font color. Then when a new font color appears in the column, I would like it to reset and then number the rows again. Pretty much create a line item column.

I found a code that kind of worked but it wasn't what I needed.

[image]

I tried other codes but nothing I found worked.

Comment: How is the data colored?  Conditional Formatting or manually?  Basically, what is rule that determines the change in colors?

Comment: Always helps to include the code you tried (even if it didn't work)

Comment: I'm assuming its manually colored. I'm asking for a friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You could use this function to test the font color:

```
Option Explicit
Function TextColour(RG As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    TextColour = RG.Font.Color
End Function
```

### Then use it like this:

[image: EUsage]

### Example:

[image]

Comment: Does **not** work with conditional formatting.